# Is "it's it" a legitimate phrase?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

We usually say "that's it" in English. I was curious to know can we also say "it's it"? Is it used in English?

Comment: I doubt people say that, and if they did, what would be the point in doing so? Also it doesn't work in negation. "That's not it." is OK, but "It's not it." is meaningless.

Comment: @user3169 Why? It makes sense, "**It is not what we are looking for**". Or "**This thing isn't the thing we need**"

Answer (score 2):

**No**, "**It's it**" isn't a set phrase like "that's it"" and, actually, isn't possible under any circumstance to mean anything like "that's it". "**That's it**" is a set phrase that is "*used to say that something has ended*" or is "*used to say that something is correct*"

However, it is a legitimate phrase and may mean "**It is what it is**".

Comment: I asked my friend, who is a native English speaker(kiwi). He said it is right, but I never heard him using it.